# Stories and tasks not being displayed in sprint Taskboard if bugs are managed with tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

We have our user stories and corresponding tasks (set as children of the storiies) moved into particular sprint.
Along with those, we have some bugs put into the same sprint, too.

Now,

1. if we set `Working with bugs` to: `Bugs are managed with requirements` then we can see user stories and tasks on the sprint taskboard, but we don't see time allocated to bugs in work details right hand pane (neither in total teams work/allocation nor for specific person bug is assigned to).
2. if we set `Working with bugs` to `Bugs are managed with tasks` then we do not see user stories nor tasks in the taskboard at all.

Question:
Is there a way to handle bugs on the sprint taskboard along with the user storires and tasks and at the same time to have estimates on the bugs that do add up to users in Work details right hand side pane?

Answer (score 1):

This is a hierarchy quirk of ADO, which existed in TFS as well.

To answer the question, no. You can't sum up the time on tasks onto the bug out-of-the-box. In TFS there was a warehouse extension that could do this, but in ADO I don't know of any equivalent marketplace extensions.

Instead, be sure your bugs have story points, and plan based on velocity. Or have people book time onto the bug, rather than the task. Downside of this is you can't make a distinction between BA, dev, QA, CS effort on the bug without having custom fields on the work item template for each role.

Comment: So, if i understand you correctly, if same developer works on both tasks and bugs within the same sprint, we have to plan 2 lines of work for him separately? one for tasks and then whatever time is left, we plan it for bugs in a separate board?

Comment: btw, is there some conceptual reason behind this or is it purely a technical limitation because of the system design?

Comment: You plan based on an amount of capacity, and the sprint board should show whether or not that person is over-committed in the Work Details panel. If you task up everything in sprint planning and add effort to everything in the sprint, it should all reflect onto the work details. I don't know about the reasoning behind it, but it's I'm sure Microsoft has some logical reasoning for this. I assume you're using the Agile template, rather than CMMI.

Comment: yes, we use agile (scrum). what i don't understand is: if we plan based on tasks, we see capacity and sum of estimates of tasks in the work details for a given person. but we don't see it for bugs assigned to that person. So, if same person works on both, tasks and bugs, how do we see work details for that person combined: tasks and bugs? if we do that (by changing the way tasks are handled) - then we don't see any work items on the sprint board.

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone also looking into the solution.

First, in `Team configuration` choose an option `Bugs are managed with requirements`.
What that does is it puts bugs at the same level as user stories.

Now, just as you have tasks under user stories, you estimate those tasks and the sum of the estimates from child tasks are rolled up to the parent story, exactly the same setup goes fos bugs.

You create a bug and for that bug you create chils tasks and estimate those tasks.

With this setup, bug related tasks  assigned to different people do show in work details pane next to people tasks are assigned to.